# t-statistic from AR estimation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, statistics, estimation

I use Matlab2016a to estimate an AR model on a few hundred time series.

```
Mdl = arima(1,0,0);
EstMdl = estimate(Mdl,TimeSeries_i);
```

The estimation itself works fine. It's my goal to store the t-statistic of the AR coefficient in a variable. `EstMdl` only contains the coefficient estimate but not the standard error or the t-statistic.

Since the screen print out reports the t-statistic, it should be possible to store the value somehow.

I've been searching for the solution for quite a while now but no success.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Best regards,
JI

Answer (score 0):

The [estimate](http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/arima.estimate.html) function returns multiple fields, but you are only assigning the first one in your call

```
EstMdl = estimate(Mdl,TimeSeries_i);
```

Try using

```
[EstMdl,EstParamCov,logL,info] = estimate(Mdl,TimeSeries_i);
```

instead.